# Unable to restart Apache on Mac after upgrading php 7.1 to 7.2 with homebrew

Tags: php, apache

After I upgraded php 7.1 to 7.2 I can no longer restart Apache. I tried to upgrade it with homebrew following the instructions on the web and I think I did something wrong.

```
php -v
PHP 7.2.15 (cli) (built: Feb 26 2019 10:43:45) ( NTS )
```

shows that i have it.

When I try to restart Apache it throws the errors shown below:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

> AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot
>   [/usr/local/opt/httpd/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
>
> AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot
>   [/usr/local/opt/httpd/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
>
> AH00526: Syntax error on line 144 of
>   /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:
>
> SSLCertificateFile: file '/usr/local/etc/httpd/server.crt' does not
>   exist or is empty

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something happened with your Apache config, whether it has been reset, or Apache is looking elsewhere.

You can try `apachectl -V` to see where they are being loaded from.

Additionally, I'm not a homebrew user, but it looks as if homebrew installed Apache should be evoked as `httpd`.

This may help as an additional resource:

https://joostvanveen.com/a-28/install-and-configure-apache-2-on-mojave-with-homebrew

Comment: all i did, i deleted httpd by homebrew, and deleted 7.2
so now I am back to where it was before. don't want to mess with it anymore)))
still, have no idea how to upgrade to 7.2 by using internal upgrade without using homebrew.

many thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with virtual hosts after a recent upgrade; I've temporarily fixed it by commenting out these two lines in httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
Include /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

That got things working for me, as I can live without vhosts and needed a quick fix.